# .width is the same...but they're obviously different

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a numerous amount of displayobjects that I made using Adobe Illustrator. I am trying to get them to be exactly the same width and height as my **mobile** device's stage.

Should be simple....but I have some that are off, and some that are about a pixel less...

I don't mind that they are a bit stretched internally. What matters is getting them to cover the screen when I want.

Take this scene for instance...
[image]

Just to be sure [my resize script](http://pastebin.com/KS8jwLec) was working, I added a before and after trace statement to my script and resized it as soon as I called the function to display it.

```

```
trace("!!! Profile scene width = " + profileScene_mc.width);
trace("!!! stage stageWidth = " + stage.stageWidth);
trace("!!! stage width = " + stage.width);
profileScene_mc.width = stage.stageWidth;
trace("!!! Profile scene width = " + profileScene_mc.width);
trace("!!! stage stageWidth = " + stage.stageWidth);
trace("!!! stage width = " + stage.width);
```

```

Traces...

```

```
!!! Profile scene width = 480.05
!!! stage stageWidth = 480
!!! stage width = 2681.65
!!! Profile scene width = 480.05
!!! stage stageWidth = 480
!!! stage width = 2681.65
```

```

Clearly this profile scene is not filling up my entire stage. Nothing inside the movie clip is outside it's original bounds. The MovieClip is originally 450 by 800...I don't know what else to do or how to debug this. It's been a sore in my project for the past few weeks. I was going to just break it all in a bitmap and then recreate it if I couldn't figure it out but I'd rather not fall back on that.

Comment: Did you set the correct stage.scaleMode, stage.align and so on?

Comment: Yep. And onresize I call that resize function

Comment: Ugh. Well. If I were you I would start with adding some kind of code-driven ruler (e.g. short black strokes every 5 pixels, long black strokes every 10, fat red strokes every 100) just to see where 0 is, where 480 is, etc. I'd also draw them with 1px wide fills instead of lines to see if they get antialiased which would show if the content is scaled to perfect 100% or not. Then, I'd check every and each display container up to the stage itself to check their scaleX properties.

Comment: Think I'll just.... Remake the movieclip real quick... Thought it would be as simple as an error in my code.

Comment: No, hold on. This is bugging me.

It thinks it's 477 initially when it lists as 450 under it's properties. https://snag.gy/PRLBEq.jpg

Comment: Breaking all the components down to a bitmap I get this a properly scaled image. https://snag.gy/7zStZ1.jpg I honestly might just do the math difference on this one..I can only assume there's something nested inside the movieclip that is out of bounds and causing it to ovextend..